# How to change the version of package in package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal

If I uninstall a package from my project like this:

```
npm uninstall react
```

the line related to this package in package.json file does not disappear, and then when I install a different version of this package, like this:

```
npm install react@15.0.0
```

the package gets installed to the node_modules, but the version in package.json remains to be unupdated, meaning that it is still the old version of a package, that I had before the uninstallation.

**How to delete / update / change the version in package.json through terminal?**

Comment: What version of `npm` are you using? Did you notice a file called `package-lock.json`?

Comment: Also, `ncu` may be useful for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `--save` to the command in both install and uninstall cases.

This way, when **uninstalling** with --save, the package's line will be erased from package.json as well as from node_modules. And when **installing** with --save, the package's line will be added to the package.json, as well as the node_modules.

So, you should go like that, for example:

```
npm uninstall react --save    
npm install react@15.0.0 --save
```

Comment: you could just  npm install react@15.0.0 --save since the package will update itself

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asked about changing the version *in* `package.json`, I'll add a quick answer showing that.  Simply change the line in `package.json` to specify the exact version like so:

```
"react": "15.0.0",
```

save, and then run `npm install`.
You can check which exact version is installed by looking in `package-lock.json` as well.